# Separate application logic threads and servlet threads in a WAR project

Tags: java, multithreading, rest, servlets, jersey

I've created a working RESTful jersey application, build as a **JAR**, that has a local module of classes with a main class `Converter` that contains functions like `public static Pipe fromDNAtoRNA(String chr, int start, int end, Strand str)`, and has `public static void main(String[] args)` that runs `Converter.register()`, which initializes local objects using remote repositories, and `Converter.runJettyServer()` that creates a jetty server on port 8080.

The REST interface is in the class `RestfulConverter`, which just sort of wraps the functions of `Converter`. Here's a sample:

```
@GET
@Path("/from/dna/chr/{chr-num}/strand/{str-type}/{start}..{end}/to/rna")
@Produces("application/javascript")
public String doDNA2RNA(@PathParam("chr-num") String chr,
        @PathParam("str-type") int str, @PathParam("start") int start,
        @PathParam("end") int end, @QueryParam("callback") String callback) {
    Pipe ans = null;
    try {
        switch (str) {
        case 1:
            ans = Converter
                    .fromDNAtoRNA(chr, start, end, Converter.FORWARD); ... }
```

Now I need the application to be a **WAR** file, which in my experience doesn't usually let the programmer define a `main` method.

I'm using `org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer` as a sole servlet. How should I use the `Converter.register()` to initialize my objects, before any one could use the REST interface?

I've tried to extend the `org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer` with a `RESTServlet` class, and override the `init()` method like this (*snippet-1*):

```
public void init() throws ServletException {
    super.init();
    try {
        Converter.main(null);
    } catch (DAOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But this throws `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/Handler`

How should I approach this? 
What if I want to update my objects on some time interval (like using `Converter.register()` every 4 hours without interrupting REST interface cilents)? 
How do I separate the servlet/REST logic from partitions of my application logic using different threads? 
Should I define a new classloader?

I have no experience with defining classloaders and multiple threads, and I've tried to look for tutorials, but didn't find anything that can help my particular situation.

**EDIT** 
Here's the full error log after regarding *snippet-1* :

```
May 06, 2015 1:15:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/server/Handler
    at il.ac.ariel.concord.service.RESTServlet.init(RESTServlet.java:16)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:817)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1517)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1474)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1157)
    ... 22 more

May 06, 2015 1:15:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet Extended Jersey
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1157)
    at il.ac.ariel.concord.service.RESTServlet.init(RESTServlet.java:16)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:817)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1517)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1474)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**EDIT 2:** 
After eliminating previous imports of jetty server on the `Converter` class, *snippet-1* worked fine.

Comment: @Deepika: what information exactly are you looking for in the error log?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://blog.eisele.net/2010/12/seven-ways-to-get-things-started-java.html in particular the bit on Startup Servlets

> @Startup Servlet
>
> The old fashioned way. You can do whatever logic is
>   needed within your startup servlet. This is a simple servlet in
>   general which gets a `>load-on-startup<` parameter in your web.xml or
>   the `@WebServlet(name="startup", loadOnStartup="2")` annotation. This
>   servlet has a load-at-startup priority of 2, meaning any servlet with
>   a load priority lower than 2 will be loaded before this one, and those
>   greater than 2 after. If you have an init() method which is called by
>   the servlet container to indicate to a servlet that the servlet is
>   being placed into service and a destroy() method which is called by
>   the servlet container to indicate to a servlet that the servlet is
>   being taken out of service.
>
> `public class StartupServlet extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet {`
>
> `public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException { ....`
>   `}`
>
> `public void destroy() { .... }  }`

If you want to do things on a timed basis, you should look into the `@Timeout` annotation http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html though this only works on a full Java EE application server like Wildfly